Is defined but never used error for generic infer
Intuitively it seems there shouldn't be any error here:
type Penultimate<T extends any[]> = T extends [
  ...infer Init,
  infer Result,
  infer Last,
]
  ? Result
  : never;

export type { Penultimate };

but Typescript generates

error TS6133: 'Init' is declared but its value is never read.
error TS6133: 'Last' is declared but its value is never read.

Should I just // @ts-ignore it or is there something I could do more properly here?

• Are you using --noUnusedParameters or something? I see TS6133 in my IDE but it's just a tooltip, not an error.  I wouldn't ever want to see errors for such things, but maybe you have different requirements? What are your tsconfig settings? • If you actually want to have an unused thing you can often name it with a leading underscore as shown in this playground link to acknowledge that it's just a placeholder.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

For what it's worth, if you don't use those types, then you don't need to infer them, which seems to be what the compiler is pushing you towards. See: https://tsplay.dev/NrYy3w Note this will also trigger the @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars eslint rule. Does that answer your question or do you really want to keep the infers here?

@AlexWayne, yea, it does, you can leave it as an answer

You only need infer if you you want to actually use the types being inferred.
So this:
type Penultimate<T extends any[]> = T extends [
  ...infer Init,
  infer Result,
  infer Last,
]
  ? Result
  : never;

Is the same as:
type Penultimate<T extends any[]> = T extends [
  ...unknown[],
  infer Result,
  unknown,
]
  ? Result
  : never;

You can ask typescript to match the pattern, and just infer the part you want to use as a type.
And doing so prevent any unused type names, so no you'll get no warnings from Typescript or eslint.
See playground
